# Return regex match from filtered SQL Query as a field

Tags: sql-server, regex, sql-server-2012

I need to query some information based on a Regex Match. But besides filtering the information by using regex, I also want to show the matched content as a new field.

Example:

```
DECLARE @example TABLE ( field VARCHAR(100) )

INSERT INTO @example VALUES (' generic info A #123# ')
INSERT INTO @example VALUES (' chewbacca #778# info B ')
INSERT INTO @example VALUES (' do not retrieve ')
INSERT INTO @example VALUES (' #456# balbalba ')

SELECT * FROM @example WHERE field LIKE '%[0-9][0-9][0-9]%'
```

My query returns:

```
|field
|-----------------------------
| generic info A #123# 
| chewbacca #778# info B 
| #456# balbalba
```

And I would like to know if there's a way of getting the matched info in another field, as this example:

```
|match |field
|------|-----------------------------
|#123# | generic info A #123# 
|#778# | chewbacca #778# info B 
|#456# | #456# balbalba
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is using substring and patindex functions like so (in other words use patindex function to get first position of mathced string and then "cut" the characters needed using substring):

```
DECLARE @example TABLE ( field VARCHAR(100) )

INSERT INTO @example VALUES (' generic info A #123# ')
INSERT INTO @example VALUES (' chewbacca #778# info B ')
INSERT INTO @example VALUES (' do not retrieve ')
INSERT INTO @example VALUES (' #456# balbalba ')

SELECT e.field, SUBSTRING(E.field, patindex('%[0-9][0-9][0-9]%', e.field)-1, 5) as match
FROM @example e
WHERE e.field LIKE '%[0-9][0-9][0-9]%'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked. I hoped some kind of regex similar to C#'s one would be available. But the most important here is for it to work =-) If my regex returned a variable sized string would this result still be possible to be achieved?